# why files are not updated through installshield installer

Tags: installshield-2011

I have added pdb file in installshield installer. I want to do minor upgrade.But, files for which version is changed, the installer does not upgrade the files. Why?

Answer (score 0):

[File Versioning Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [REINSTALLMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)=omus

Change this property with care, though, especially if your installation includes merge modules. I wouldn't go past REINSTALLMODE=emus (by which I mean avoid REINSTALLMODE=amus).